# Adding inline policy to access S3 for AWS SSO

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-sso

I have permission set created in AWS, and I am creating an INLINE policy where I want to give access to a specific bucket .

when I am trying below it works fine which is something I don't want, however when add resource to like and resource arn `arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name` or `arn:aws:s3:::*data*`
it shows me insufficient privilege and I am not able to access.

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

policy I am using which Is not working

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::data*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::data*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Provide the actual policies that you used and exact error messages that you get.

Comment: @Marcin I have added the policy that I am using to the question itself

Answer (score 0):

The policy should be:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: I have tried this too, it is also not working
I tried both inline and customer managed policy. I think for SSO inline policy there is something else it require

Comment: Also what is the difference between the policy I am using and you shared as solution, aint both same?

Comment: @waseemmir  It should be`data/*`, not `data*/*`. My answer is correct and you can't have two `*`.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i do in summary...

create the permission set... create the inline policy, then attach the policy

```
resource "aws_ssoadmin_permission_set" "permset" {
      name             = "name"
      description      = ""
      instance_arn     = tolist(data.aws_ssoadmin_instances.instance.arns)[0]
      session_duration = "PT10H"
    
    }

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policyname" {
  statement {
    sid = "s3actions"
    actions = "s3:*"
    "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::data*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::data*/*"
        ]
  }
}

resource "aws_ssoadmin_permission_set_inline_policy" "policyattach" {
  instance_arn       = tolist(data.aws_ssoadmin_instances.instance.arns)[0]
  permission_set_arn = aws_ssoadmin_permission_set.permset.arn
  inline_policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.policyname.json
}
```

I hope this works for you